# how to call didUpdateToLocation after shake on iPhone

Tags: ios, core-location

I'm trying get location updates when the user shakes his iPhone, I'm enabling GPS on receiving the shake event, but my problem is that the `didUpdateToLocation` method is not called. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        
    }
    - (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        if(event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
        {
            [self first];
        }
    }
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
   // NSLog(@"OldLocation %f %f", oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, oldLocation.coordinate.longitude);
   // NSLog(@"NewLocation %f %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    
  NSString * currentLat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    NSLog(@"currentLat%@",currentLat);
    NSString * currentLong = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    NSLog(@"currentLong%@",currentLong);
}
-(void)first
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"called");
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that location-services are enabled and App has access to location-services (under iPhone Settings -> Location Services). The method you are using is deprecated since iOS 6. You should use

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

I would recommend you implementing following method as well for debugging purpose.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

ps. I'm not sure about the scope for locationManager in your method **first**. Why don't you make it (strong) property and then initialise it in **viewDidLoad** and only call **startUpdatingLocation** in your method **first**.

Comment: thanks for reply i need get latitude and longitude value after shake.So Please give me any idea about how to get latitude and longitude value when i shake simulator or mobile